# Smooth shading not working

Tags: shadows

As shown in the image below, I have a simple object that I want to shade smooth, so my final model won't be too heavy since I'm gonna repeat it thousands of times.

It appears that some faces are correctly shaded smooth, but others are not at all. When I saw this I immediately went to check if auto smooth was on and the angle setting here caused it, but this is not the case.

Everything looks normal in the lookdev and the solid shaded mode, also my topology shouldn't cause any of these problems.

Am I overlooking something very obvious here? I've been working with blender for hundreds of hours, but have no idea what is causing this. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: It does look like the same effect, but I still get the same effect when I subdivide 2 or 3 times. This would mean that the proposed cause in that post, 'too little geometry' is not in fact the cause in my situation. Thank you for your quick reply btw